# python list.append() problem when storing class objects

Tags: python, django, list, class, model

I have a problem when the some class objects are going to be added to the list in a loop process.
let's say I have a database `[ 'kid' , 'parent' , 'grandfather' ]` with many records.
i have a class:

```
class Person:
     name
     children
     grandchildren
```

I make a loop (I know it's a bad idea and that I can simply use queries) and look for every `grandfather`. an instance of class stores the data of every `grandfather` and at the end is appended to a list called `Persons_List`. Here is the Code:

```
p = Person()
Persons_List = list()
pr = "" #parents
gr = "" #grandfather
for i in my_database.objects.all().order_by('grandfather'):
     if gr != i.grandfather:
        gr = i.grandfather
        pr = i.parent
        if p.name !="":
            Persons_List.append(p) # [:] raises Error and deepcopy not working
            p.name = ""
            p.parents.clear()
            p.grandchildren.clear()
        p.name = i.grandfather
        p.children.append(i.parent)
        p.grandchildren.append(i.kid)
     else:
        if pr != i.parent:
           pr = i.parent
           try:
               p.children.remove(pr)
           except: None
           p.children.append(pr)
           p.grandchildren.append(i.kid)
Persons_List.append(p)  #Adds The Last p To The List
```

the problem is that in the end the Data Stored in list is wrong and messy. the name is the last `p.name`. and the `children` and `grandchildren` are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First: You are missing indentation at `Persons_List.append(p)`.
You are currently appending `p` to the list outside of your for-loop.

Another point might be that you are overriding your `p` object over and over in your loop.

That is because you create `p = Person()` outside of your for-loop and inside of it you are changing the referenced object.

If you create a new object inside your for-loop, it should work. Example:

```py
list = []
for i in queryset:
    p = Person()
    # do stuff
    list.append(p)

print(list)  # your finished list
```

Comment: Dear Sir. Thank you for reply. The Persons_List.append(p) at the end is out of loop. This code adds the last p to the list. Only the last one. I've also tried p = person() instead of those three line under the line Person_List.append(p) in if body. And the result is the same. If you add some code to print p and the items in Persons_List in the middle of loop. You see that p works well. But the list has strange behaviour. Anyway thanks for reply